# Fabric.js: Error when loading image from parameterized URL

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to load an image from an external URL. The image is retrieved dynamically from a database and is therefore not a direct path. An example of such URL is: http://192.192.168.12:8080/api/imageServer?file=imageName.jpeg. The response in an actual jpeg image; when I add the URL to an image tag or directly in the browser the image is shown. When I try to load the image into Fabric.js I only get the console message "Error loading " without any other message.

This is part of our code:

```js
var updateCanvas = function () {
        self.canvas.clear();
        if (self.selectedImage() && self.canvas) {
            try {
                fabric.Image.fromURL(self.selectedImage().imageUrl, function (oImg) {
                    if (oImg._element == null) {
                        stickyToast(translations().Error, translations().img_bind_error, "error");
                        return;
                    }
                    self.canvas.clear();


                    var canvasHeight = 500;
                    var ratio = canvasHeight / oImg.height;
                    var canvasWidth = oImg.width * ratio;


                    //Define all filters that will be used on image
                    oImg.filters[0] = new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness({
                        brightness: 0
                    });
...
```

I've tried upgrading to the latest version of fabric.js but to no avail. Is  there another method I need to use download the image?

Comment: May be you are getting error because of cross origin, try `fabric.Image.fromURL(url,callback,{crossOrigin:'anonymous'})`

Comment: Does this error only occur with certain browsers?
I have the same error, but it only occurs under iOS (any browser) or on the Safari browser under MacOS.